# Knockout.js returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to fetch some user data from ajax and return it in my html to update the UI. 
For some reason I cant get it to work.

I have the following knockout:

```
function User(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
}

function UserViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.users(), function(user) { return !user.email() });
    });


    // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
    $.getJSON("/admin/ajax-get-add-user-json.do", function(allData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new User(item) });
        self.users(mappedTasks);
        console.log(allData);
        console.log(allData.name);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
```

Then I return it like this in the html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: users, visible: users().length > 0">
    <li data-bind="text: email"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

But when I use the console.log for .name it returns undefined in my console. 
And it doesnt print anything in the HTML either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the response property of all data:

```
function(allData) {
    var data = allData.response;
    var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function(item) { return new User(item) });
    self.users(mappedTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I change to : 


`code
        $.getJSON("/admin/ajax-get-add-user-json.do", function(allData) {
                var data = JSON.parse(allData);
                var mappedUsers = $.map(data, function(item) { return new User(item) });
                self.users(mappedUsers);
        }); code`


The console returns "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: @PatrickZiebellThøgersen Then quite probably you have an issue with the data you retrun from the server. Are you sure that you serialize the data in a JSON format before you send them to the client. If you post the relevenat server side code it would be ideal. Thanks

Comment: The response is similar to this: 

response:[ {

0:

email:“aaa@aaa.dk”
name:"Patrick"

1:
email:”bbb@bbb.com”
name: "Kasper”

success: true
}]

Comment: You could validate if a string is a valid json at http://jsonlint.com/. I think that if you copy/paste there your string and check the validity you will see that it's not a valid json string.

Comment: It validates it as valid JSON :-/

Comment: hmm...Then the problem is in another place. My bad :(. We have taken the wrong path. Maybe the JSON.parse is not need at all, as I read here, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. The problem it might be in the data we return or they we read them. They are in JSON format but we might not return what we expect. Normally, I would expect something like this  `[{email:“aaa@aaa.dk”, name:"Patrick"}, { email:”bbb@bbb.com” name: "Kasper”}]`. So we have to find out why this is not happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131888/discussion-between-christos-and-patrick-ziebell-thogersen).

Comment: Yeah it is also what it returns. My bad about the 0 and 1. Just took it form console. 
It looks like this in the JSONLINT: 

`{
 "response": [{



  "email": "aaa@aaa.dk",
  "name": "Patrick"

 }, {

  "email": "bbb@bbb.com",
  "name": "Kasper"

 }],
 "success": true
}`

Comment: @PatrickZiebellThøgersen Please have a look at the update and let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: It still logs undefined on `console.log(allData.name);` and doesnt show anything in the UI :-/

Comment: Apparently `allData.name` should be undefined. `allData` hasn't any property called name. It has two properties `response` and `success`.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you point me in a direction that can make me fix it?